# How to find the non zero negative and positive element for each column

Tags: matlab

How to find the non zero negative/ positive element for each column.

`size A= 3*100` and for each column we have one non zero negative/positive element. How to find the indices of those elements without using a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
B = A>0;
C = A<0;
D = B-C;
```

`D` now contains a -1 if the entry is negative and a 1 if the entry is positive. Columns can be extracted by using the indices:

```
D(:,1) %first column
D(:,2) %second column
```

etc.

```
[row,column] = find(A>0)
```

would also do the trick and gives you indices as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.. I am new user in stackover flow .. so was not able to find the edit button.. and by mistake I have submitted the answer..I think by using abs function will be difficult to identify whether the number was negative or positive..I want to know separately the indices of the value ( negative as well as positive) and would like to check for each column..